# Traversing to view did load after popping the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller

Hi I am new to Stack Overflow so my apologies for any mistakes.I want to ask that whenever we pop to the previous view,how can we make the control go to the previous view `viewDidLoad`? In my application,it pops to the previous view but i want to reload the previous view so i want it to go to `viewDidLoad`.Thanks in advance.
I have used the following code.

```
[self.navigationController popViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: Question is confusing.. Please elaborate. `viewWillAppear`gets called when your xib is loaded or class is called..

Comment: I wanted to call 'view did load' of the previous view.But i guess that coding in 'view will appear' will solve my problem.thanks for replying.

Comment: Yeah.. It will solve your issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do that. However, when you return to a view, the code in `viewWillAppear` will get executed (basically, the code in there is executed every time the view appears - as the name suggests).

Suggestion: split your code from `viewDidLoad` into 2 parts:

1. one chunk of code that should only be executed once - which must be
   left there
2. a second chunk of code that you want to be executed every time your
   view appears, which you'll move in `viewWillAppear`

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

When you pop a view and go back to previous view then 'viewWillAppear`and`viewDidAppear` methods of view controller are called.

Following is the calling hierarchy -

`viewDidLoad`- This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory.

`viewWillAppear` - This method is called before the receiver’s view is about to be added to a view hierarchy.

`viewDidAppear`- Notifies the view controller that its view was added to a view hierarchy.

Checkout UIViewController class reference for details of these view controller life cycle methods - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

So based upon requirement, you need to decide and what all UIElement you want to be loaded only once use in `viewDidLoad` and element on which you want to do refresh upon  returning use `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear`.

Comment: So will i have to do the coding in view will appear? and thanks for the quickest reply.

Comment: Thanks rishi..this document is really very useful for newbies like me.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that we a trick .

1. Make a method and paste all your code from view did load in this method .
2. Call that method from view did load .
3. Call that method from view will appear .

**This this not possible to call view did load but you can do all this from view will appear like view did load**

Thanks